# steam / libc6 (i386) installation fails

Tags: linux-mint, apt, glibc, steam

`uname -a` returns
`Linux mypcname 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a` returns

```
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa
Release:    19.1
Codename:   tessa
```

I did `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` successfully, i386 is listed in foreign architectures.

When I run `sudo apt-get install steam` or `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386` it returns:

`sudo apt-get install steam`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dictionaries-common : Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not going to be installed
 steam:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgpg-error0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Error of `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dictionaries-common : Depends: debconf (>= 1.5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                                debconf-2.0
                       Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not going to be installed
         Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.28-2) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.28-2 is to be installed
 libssl1.1 : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                      debconf-2.0
 libsystemd0 : PreDepends: libgcrypt20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libxml2 : Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-cli : Depends: libedit2 (>= 2.11-20080614-4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.2-readline but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-common : Depends: php-common (>= 1:35) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-json : Depends: php-common (>= 1:35) but it is not going to be installed
 php7.2-opcache : Depends: php-common (>= 1:35) but it is not going to be installed
 tzdata : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                   debconf-2.0
 ucf : Depends: debconf (>= 1.5.19) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: coreutils (>= 5.91)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I searched for solutions online for hours and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt check && sudo apt upgrade`, then try again.

Comment: Already did. Changes: Nothing. @ajgringo619

Comment: Can you install anything else? What does `apt install -f` return?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes, `apt-get install -f` ends successful / with no results and I can install other software without problems.

Comment: Do you any held packages (`apt-mark showhold`)? Is this the first 32-bit program you've tried to install?

Comment: no packages are held and yes, it is the first. @ajgringo619

Comment: You have many dependency issues, use `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`, to be able to better navigate between proposed alternatives. `apt-get install aptitude` then just `aptitude` (it's a TUI program).

Comment: @uprego aptitude ends by changing/installing nothing. Same errors as with apt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to install it via apt, but flatpak worked:

`flatpak install flathub com.valvesoftware.Steam`

Problem solved.

Thanks to @ajgringo619

Comment: In Debian, I was able to install it via `apt` on a 686 box with i386 listed in foreign architectures... only to get the same message as when installing it on a i386 box, "steam browser disabled" with the same link to a non-explanatory page. Then I found your answer :-)
So definitely, use flatpak!